# How to create scaffold with many field relation from various two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I want to create a scaffold for table with below references. Here`transport_supervisor_id`,`manager_id`,`loading_supervisor_id`these things comes under user table references

```
  load_type_id (belongs_to load_type)
  load_pick_from_date (date)
  load_pick_to_date (date)
  price (decimal presision 9,2)
  transport_supervisor_id (belongs_to user)
  manager_id (belongs_to user)
  loading_supervisor_id (belongs_to user)
  company_id (belongs_to company)
```

How can i create like this? i want to create this rails g scaffolding command itself only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance;

```
rails generate scaffold manager name:string

rails g scaffold supervisor name:string manager:belongs_to
```

Output;

```
create_table "supervisors", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.integer  "manager_id"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "managers", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I hope, It'll help you in this case.